# iOS invalidate beta version of an app when Final version is live

Tags: ios, development-environment, ios-provisioning, beta-testing

Hi I was just wondering if there was a way to stop a beta version of an app once it's no longer beta and live in the AppStore. like many iOS devs I have been using beta testers to test my apps before release, I was wondering if there is any way to stop the beta versions working on a certain date or revoke the provisioning profile as they use:

```
get-task-allow
```

or do there beta versions just work forever or until the provisioning profile expires.

Any input would be appreciated as I've searched & searched but can't find an answer.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The app will keep working until the provisioning profile expires. Unless you take steps ahead of time, there is nothing you can do other than ask the user to delete the app.

I add code to my beta versions that makes the app simply exit some number of days after being built. Of course this can be worked around by changing the date on the device to a past date but for me that's not a problem.

There are other options of course but you need to ask yourself how much effort is really needed to keep an old beta from working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If I was willing to put a lot of effort in on this occasion (for reasons I won't bore you with) what options did you have in mind.

Comment: Having the app "phone home" to your server would be one option. Or have the app contact NTP server to work around the device's date setting. But both require Internet access. Of course you could make the beta fail if there is no network. But a good hacker will get around any of this if motivated enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the beta is already out there with no modifications of code to invalidate it, So on this occasion, I assume there is nothing I can do but let the guy continue to use/misuse it, until the profile expires.

Comment: Correct, as stated in the 1st paragraph of my answer. You're stuck this time around. BTW - don't forget to upvote/accept an answer to indicate it answered your question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I hadn't forgotten as I am a fellow hatter what it comes to users not accepting answers, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in-built way to invalidate an app.  You can build a date check into the beta versions of your app so that it won't run after a certain date - people could change the date on their device, but most wouldn't bother.

I typically reward my beta testers with a free download of the released version anyway using the codes available from iTunesConnect